# How Entity Framework do when convert Entity Model Validation from server to something that client can understand and validate?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I want to validate a form with angularjs, absolutely in client side. And I want to use the [Annotation Atribute] from entity model class to validate.
But I don't know how and what the {thing} Entity Framework generated for client can read it and validate. Can I get that {thing}? and how?

Comment: Is your entity model already viewmodel (you pass your entity model to view without any transfomation)?

Comment: Yes, it's view model.

Comment: Then you can read annotation attributes with reflection and generate for each of them angular's markup in view for validation.

Comment: That's the problem I'm solving. I dont know how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get attributes of current property of current type (example):

```
var propertiesWithValidationAttributes = typeof (YourModelClass).GetProperties()
            .Select(
                p =>
                    new
                    {
                        name = p.Name,
                        attributes = p.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<ValidationAttribute>().ToArray()
                    });
```

it returns enumerable of propertyNames with collection of validation attributes on each of them.

Comment: Thank you, it help me more.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kirill's answer, there is a list of validation attributes that you should know. Validate each attributes in client code with a switch-case based on name of attribute and validation attributes array you received.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much.